# Loop through a form loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, loops

I have a form like this:

```
<form name="calc" action="" id="calc">
<?php for($i=0; $i<15; $i++) { ?>
<input type="text" name="txt1[$i]" onkeyup="calcNumber()"/>
<input type="text" name="txt2[$i]" onkeyup="calcNumber()"/>
<input type="text" name="txt3[$i]" onkeyup="calcNumber()"/>
<span id="tot[$i]"></span>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

And this is javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcNumber() {

for(var j=0; j<15; j++) {

var totNumber[j] = document.calc.txt1[j].value + document.calc.txt2[j].value + document.calc.txt3[j].value;

document.getElementById('tot[j]').innerHTML = totNumber[j];
}

}
</script>
```

No error.. But no result either. Please let me know what I have done wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the output HTML as well, not just the PHP...

Comment: @mkoryak do you mean I have to write the input fields like this? <input type="text" name="txt1[<?php echo $i;?>]" id="txt1[<?php echo $i;?>]"/>

Comment: Does anyone have any other ideas? I still couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem, just insert array after `tot` in `function calcNumber()`, but not within `tot`.

Thank you guys so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your html to the following.

```
<input type="text" name="txt1[<?php echo $i;?>]" onkeyup="calcNumber()"/>
<input type="text" name="txt2[<?php echo $i;?>]" onkeyup="calcNumber()"/>
<input type="text" name="txt3[<?php echo $i;?>]" onkeyup="calcNumber()"/>
<span id="tot[<?php echo $i;?>]"></span>
```

And the current line of your javascript:

`document.getElementById('tot[' + j + ']').innerHTML = totNumber;`

`totNumber` isn't an `array`, and don't need to be in this case.

**The issue**

Your rendered html is exactly the html you provided on your question, `$i` doesn't get replaced by the number because it's not inside `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: dont forget to fix your html and include an `id` attribute on the inputs ;)

Comment: Thanks for your straight to the point explanation. Now I have understood that the problem in the form. But I don't know why I still couldn't get it to work. The <span> field is still blank.